# C#, is there 'Defer Call' like golang?

Tags: c#, destructor

golang support 'Defer Call' and when c++, I use this trick(?).

```
struct DeferCall
{
   DeferCall() {}
   ~DeferCall() { doSomeThing(); }
}

void SomeMethod()
{
    DeferCall deferCall;
    ...
}
```

how can I do this in c# ?

I need like this [golang defer tutorial](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/12)

Comment: What is the aim of defer call, here, it will continue later post some other action?

Comment: Although the trick can be possibly used for multiple purposes, the cleanup it is often used for in C# is implemented with explicit `IDisposable` interface.

Comment: Please note @WiktorZychla point is very important, in C# cleanup may need a finalizer which automatically cleans, if user fails to calls Dispose method explicitly, so you may not do anything in this regard in C#, it will clean when no more referenced

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: what you just said is that there are no defers in C#. What I say is what is the idiomatic way of cleanups defers are often used for.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj check this link please.. [golang defer tutorial](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/12)

Comment: @WiktorZychla you may say by virtue of C# implementation it has implicit `Defer`, but by no means I am saying there's no `Defer`. Most of the Dispose driven clean up action has to be explicitly called by the used failing which it will lead to a leak

Comment: @MrinalKamboj: true, devs fail to call explicit dispose methods. By no means `Task`s and `async/await` doesn't help here. In your answer you focus on language feature, somehow ignoring what defers are used for.

Comment: @WiktorZychla if `Defer` does only clean up work, then yes I am wrong, Task, has nothing to do with it, but if its about saving a work to be done later, as understood from the definition, then Task have a role to play out here

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I picked up the following definition of the `Defer Call` in `GoLang` from [here](https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover)

**A defer statement pushes a function call onto a list. The list of saved calls is executed after the surrounding function returns. Defer is commonly used to simplify functions that perform various clean-up actions.**

**C# version:**

**Option 1:**

- Use a `Task` API
- Wrap your `DeferCall` method in the `Task`
- Execute at the right time either Manually using `Start()` method or for the function post which you want to continute, wrap that in another Task object and execute using `ContinueWith`API, which will chain tasks to execute one after another

**Option 2:**

- Can make whole call chain `Async-Await`, where everything post `await` keyword is executed the main call finish, this is standard Asynchronous implementation

Comment: Tasks are not an option here. "The list of saved calls is executed after the surrounding function returns". Tasks don't behave like this.

Comment: Why would Task not work like this, you can certainly execute them once a call return, just that it has to be explicitly executed, using `Start` or` `ContinueWith`, not an implicit continuation like `Async-Await`

Comment: I'm a down-voter too. It's clear, that defer-panic-recover are finally-throw-catch in C#. How this is related to tasks? Do you use tasks in your C# code to perform cleanup? Why did you read "defer" word, but omitted the whole sentence from the link you referred?

Comment: @Dennis That would be the exact replacement if we are only talking about clean up, but as I can understand from the definition pasted above, it is more about keeping a call aside and use it later, which is, mostly used for clean up, but not the only thing

Comment: You're stubborn man, do you know it? :) Again, `defer`s are used to execute, when surrounding method returns. They are mostly used for cleanup. Do you use tasks for cleanup?

Comment: Alright, I have no experience of `Go-Lang`, you might have used these APIs. I have certainly misunderstood the deferred execution in this case. Thanks for all the clarification.

Answer (score 17):

The nearest language equivalent will be [`try`-`finally`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx):

```
try
{
    DoSomething();
}
finally
{
    DoCleanup();
}
```

The nearest framework equivalent will be [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) + [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead("foo.txt"))
{
    // do something
}
```

Personally, `defer` term confuses me, since *this is not* "deferred execution" (schedule now - execute later, which could be implemented via tasks),
but some sort of [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) implementation.

P.S.
Assuming, that you will continue to learn golang:

- `panic` equivalent is [`throw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ah5wsex.aspx)
- `recover` equivalent is [`catch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx)

Comment: `using` was the first thing that came to my mind. It was made for pretty much the same scenarios that C++ destructors and (I'm assuming) Go defer calls were created for.

Comment: @ekflame this question should be approved. The current approved answer doesn't actually answer your question

Answer (score 13):

You can implement this using [System.Reactive.Disposables.Disposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh229378(v=vs.103))

```
void Function()
{
    string fileName = "InputFile.txt";
    using var defer = Disposable.Create(() => { File.Delete(fileName); });

    WriteFile(fileName);
    ConvertFile(fileName, "OutputFile.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but not impossible
`defer` is a keyword designed to execute functions when its parent function returns and starts executing when return statement is reached.

Since `defer` in go works like a stack, so calling deferred functions in-order results in a reverse order.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    defer fmt.Println("1")
    defer fmt.Println("2")
    defer fmt.Println("3")

    if num := 2; num == 2 {
        defer fmt.Println("4")
        return
    }
    defer fmt.Println("5")
}

// 4
// 3
// 2
// 1
```

https://play.golang.org/p/jzHG-paytBG

It's best usecases are closing file readers, database transactions, and stacking logs where closing before returning is necessary.

```golang
var count
defer println(count)
for { // forever
    count++
    if count == 100 {
        return
    }
}

defer pkg.DoCleanup()
something := pkg.DoSomething()
pkg.Add(something.ForCleanup)
pkg.Add(something.ForCleanup)

stream, _ := file.OpenRead("text.txt")
defer stream.Close()

// stream closed
// pkg cleaned
// 100
```

Workarounds would be like Dennis' answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40690576/9640539

Answer (score 0):

Not a built-in functionality or keyword in C# but you can create a defer engine which executes the deferred actions after method call is returned,
[Jess's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57354729/223752) golang `defer` usage example you can write in C# equivalent like:

```
using System.Reflection;

DeferTest test = new DeferTest();
Defer.Execute(()=> { test.Test(); });

public class DeferTest
{
    [Deferrable]
    public void Test()
    {
        int i = 0;

        Defer.Me(() => { Console.WriteLine("1"); });
        Defer.Me(() => { Console.WriteLine("2"); });
        i++;
        Defer.Me(() => { Console.WriteLine("3"); });
        Defer.Me(() => { Console.WriteLine("4"); });

        if (i > 0)
            return;

        Defer.Me(() => { Console.WriteLine("5"); });
    }
}

public class DeferrableAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DeferrableAttribute()
    {
        DeferList = new Defer();
    }

    public DeferrableAttribute(Defer d)
    {
        DeferList = d;
    }
    public Defer DeferList;
}

public class Defer
{
    private static Stack<Action> Actions { get; set; }
    static Defer() { Actions = new Stack<Action>(); }

    public static void Me(Action a)
    {
        Actions.Push(a);
    }

    public static void Execute(Action action)
    {
        action();
        while (Actions.Count > 0)
        {
            var a = Actions.Pop();
            a();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

advanced version: https://gist.github.com/nitinjs/10ce0ee2e377c88c8a9bde1ab9440336

Answer (score 0):

First: you need to follow the language patterns, in that case, using an IDisposable object.

Second: I have been written about defer in C#, follow this link https://medium.com/@schivei/implementing-go-style-defer-in-c-32ac86c4ac57

In this article, I’m using the (using) keyword, without brackets, and it’s acts the same way in golang (disposing/executing) a code lambda on the scope ends.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, several good answers, but I think I can help a little bit.

The short answer is: No, you don't have anything like golang defer in C# nor C++ (even with tricks - unkes you hack the call stack in C++ than you can have).

defer in go put's the execution of the defered function in the return of a function (just before returning). It's not scope aware (if you call a defer inside a if in go, it will be executed when the whole function return and not when the if ends for example).

But, you can use the try-finally or the dispose pattern to get a similar behaviour as explaned by other users in previous answers.

Answer (score -2):

You can use **Goto**, which isn't a sin. Here's a function with multiple points of exit, and some cleanup that must be run on every exit.

```
public void DoWork()
{
    bool result = false;

    // Some work that wants to return false
    goto wrap;

    // Some other work that wants to return true
    result = true;
    goto wrap;

    // Some other work that wants to return false
    goto wrap;
    
wrap:
    DoCleanup();
    return result;
}
```